# Showing a different XIB/NIB in an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xib, nib

I have multiple nib (xib) files and I want the user to see a different one when they tap a button. What I am looking for:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTap {
//Code for showing a different nib goes here
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I can show a different view within the nib file just fine, but I can't get it to show a different nib. How do I show a different nib when the user taps a button?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is some wonderful Apple documentation discussing everything relating to managing views.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handle switching between actual xib's, and I'm sure there are a multitude of ways to accomplish the same thing, is to have my App Delegate act as a routing center between my views.

I subscribe my App Delegate to recieve events from button presses for existing views.  When it recieves a request to switch views, such as a button press, I do something like this:

```
- (void) showLogin
{  
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]
                                                   initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Show
    self.loginViewController = loginViewController;
    [loginViewController release];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginViewController;
}
```

I set my `rootViewController` to the view I am attempting to display.  It doesn't release the old controller, but simply replaces the view being displayed.  You can place more logic in to determine if it's already displayed, close out other views, etc.  In most simplistic terms, this works for me.

Comment: Hmmm, when I try this I get two types of errors. I get a: "Unknown receiver" and an "Undeclared Identifier". What am I doing wrong? Does this only work in one project type?

Comment: Are you declaring a property to hold a reference to the controller you are attempting to display?  Are you subscribing correctly to the event being raised?

Comment: As far as the undeclared identifier, do i need to declare the View controller in a header file? If so, do I declare it in the header file of the view I want to show or a different one? How do I subscribe to the event? Sorry for any trouble, but I am new to xcode and objective-c.

Comment: As alluded to in my code above, I am storing the `loginViewController` reference exposed as a property in my AppDelegates header.  I set this so that I don't need to create a new instance of my login controller each time the function is called (not shown).  You'll need to retain a reference in the AppDelegate header for this.