# How to load a XIB in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing a different XIB/NIB in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526416/showing-a-different-xib-nib-in-an-ios-app)

Currently I have a iOS app with one view and one xib. Upon pressing a button, I'd like to display a different view with a different xib. The issue is I just don't know exactly how to do this. Currently, I am instantiating the controller with:

(The view I'm trying to load is HomeViewController. I'm currently within TipAppViewController)

```
HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
```

I'm unsure where I should go now. I'm not using a Navigation controller currently and would like not to as I don't want a blue bar at the top of the screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That looks good. My issue is that I'm currently not using a navigation controller. Would this be an issue?

Comment: @Astephen2 I've just editied my answer now it will work for you.

Comment: presentModalViewController is deprecated.

Comment: @stackmonster didn't knew about that its depreciated in iOS 6.0 but I have corrected it to right method.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you all so much.